# bzrlib version doesn't match the bzr program

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bazaar

I have just upgrade ubuntu from 10.04 - 12.04. When I used bzr to update repo it has a problem:

```
 ~/source_code/openerputils/devenvsetup$ bzr status
bzr: WARNING: bzrlib version doesn't match the bzr program.
This may indicate an installation problem.
bzrlib from ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib'] is version (2, 5, 0, 'final', 0)
```

I remove bzr by `sudo apt-get purge bzr` and bzrlib but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the system version of the bzr script. Does:

```
$ which bzr
```

return something like:

```
/usr/bin/bzr
```